# How do I amend MySQL query to count the number of times a value appears in a DB table/result?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

The following database result/table was created by joining 2 tables together using the SQL query below. What I also want to do is to display a third column which counts how many times a certain value is contained within the main_category column. An example of the desired result can be seen in the table at the bottom where the third column shows the number of times 'main category 1' appears - in this example 8 times, and that 'main category 2' appears 6 times. Does anyone know what I'd need to do to the existing query to do this? Does it involve `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`?

```
+--------------+-----------------+  
| sub_category | main_category   |  
+--------------+-----------------+  
| SubCategoryA | main category 1 |  
| SubCategoryB | main category 1 |  
| SubCategoryC | main category 1 |  
| SubCategoryD | main category 1 |  
| SubCategoryE | main category 1 |  
| SubCategoryF | main category 1 |  
| SubCategoryG | main category 1 |  
| SubCategoryH | main category 1 |  
| SubCategoryI | main category 2 |  
| SubCategoryJ | main category 2 |  
| SubCategoryK | main category 2 |  
| SubCategoryL | main category 2 |  
| SubCategoryM | main category 2 |  
| SubCategoryN | main category 2 |  
+--------------+-----------------+
```

```
  SELECT headings.heading AS sub_category,    
         primary_category AS main_category  
  FROM   TABLE1 INNER JOIN headings ON TABLE1.Heading=TABLE2.heading   

UNION

  SELECT TABLE2.heading     AS heading,
         secondary_category AS main_category   
  FROM   TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.Heading=TABLE2.heading   

ORDER BY main_category ASC
```

```
+--------------+-----------------+-------+  
| sub_category | main_category   | count |  
+--------------+-----------------+-------+  
| SubCategoryA | main category 1 |     8 |  
| SubCategoryB | main category 1 |     8 |  
| SubCategoryC | main category 1 |     8 |  
| SubCategoryD | main category 1 |     8 |  
| SubCategoryE | main category 1 |     8 |  
| SubCategoryF | main category 1 |     8 |  
| SubCategoryG | main category 1 |     8 |  
| SubCategoryH | main category 1 |     8 |  
| SubCategoryI | main category 2 |     6 |  
| SubCategoryJ | main category 2 |     6 |  
| SubCategoryK | main category 2 |     6 |  
| SubCategoryL | main category 2 |     6 |  
| SubCategoryM | main category 2 |     6 |  
| SubCategoryN | main category 2 |     6 |  
+--------------+-----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

i have take you example data provided in your question here the subquery just to show you the logic how you can do it

```
SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT( mcat) FROM `categoriesstack`

 WHERE mcat=cs.mcat) AS `count` FROM `categoriesstack` cs
```

[**Here is your fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faaf7/1)

This is how you can implement in your query but not sure that is works

```
  SELECT headings.heading AS sub_category,    
         primary_category AS main_category,
  (SELECT COUNT(primary_category) FROM `TABLE1` WHERE primary_category=TABLE1 .primary_category) AS `count`   
  FROM   TABLE1 INNER JOIN headings ON TABLE1.Heading=TABLE2.heading   

UNION

  SELECT TABLE2.heading     AS heading,
         secondary_category AS main_category,
  (SELECT COUNT(secondary_category) FROM `TABLE1` WHERE secondary_category=TABLE1 .secondary_category) AS `count`   
  FROM   TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.Heading=TABLE2.heading   

ORDER BY main_category ASC
```

Hope it works fine

Comment: thank you. This seems to be what I need, but I'm struggling to make your code work with my exact SQL. Please could you take a look at [this fiddle that I've created](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae522/2) which better illustrates what I'm trying to do and see how your sub query could work with it? The first two tables are the two that I'm joining. The third table is the result of the query that I'm trying to create. I need to add the count to the third table.

Comment: Thank you @dianuj - we're getting nearer :) I've removed the GROUP BY at the end - that was my fault as I shouldn't have grouped them in my demo table.

You can see on this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e54f5/2 that I've taken the GROUP BY away and also instead of the sub categories all being the same, I've made them different, because this is what happens in my application.

Comment: The first table in my latest fiddle is the 'headings' table. I've been trying to work out why the COUNTs are now not accurate? The first table shows that 'Main Category 1' appears a total of 13 times, but it says 12 in the COUNT column. 'Main Category 2' appears 7 times, but it has 2 different values, 3 & 4. 'Main Category 3' seems to have a correct count at 3. But 'Main Category 4' should be 1 and that doesn't appear. Strange, any ideas @dianuj ?

Comment: I've fixed some of the problems here, I was missing some values in the AREA_TABLE. So basically the issue is now that the counts from primary_category and secondary_category aren't combined into a single value. Is it possible to combine them so that each 'Main Category 1' row reads 13, rather than 12 & 1? See the new fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21a207/1